# SQL Server to postgres - Identity tables are not getting created

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, migration, database-migration

I have developed a ASP.NET Core MVC application which was connecting to a SQL Server database. Now, I changed the target database to PostgreSQL by following below steps

- Step #1 - Changed the connection string
- Step #2 - Replaced the `.HasColumnType("INTEGER")` with `.HasColumnType("BOOLEAN")`
- Step #3 - ran the command `dotnet ef database update`

But only `__EFMigrationsHistory` table got created.

`AspNetRoleClaims, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims` and other required tables are not created.

I suspect there's something wrong in this code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'IdentityContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
```

These are my packages

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.12" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.12" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.12" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.12">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

After adding below nuget packagae things worked!!

> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design